# MongoDB load balancing

Tags: mongodb

I was looking at best load balancing option for concurrent users with Mongo DB. I have looked at Master Slave replication but don't think this will load balance. Are there any open source DB load balancers for Mongo DB?

I have looked at Sequoia but looks like that project is no longer actively supported.

Please note: The data is not very huge & also not use case for sharding.

Comment: I know I am late for the party, use java driver's ReadPreference as Nearest for read load balancing across replica seeds. Write load balancing is not possible in MongoDB without sharding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

both Master Slave and Replica Sets will load balance in MongoDB, if you set slaveOK in your driver.

When slaveOK is enabled MongoDB drivers direct all reads to secondaries/slaves.

This provides relatively effective read balancing; for write balancing your only option.would be sharding.

Comment: Thanks Brendan.  On sharding, my understanding is that the key should belong to a group/pattern only then it will be effective. For ex: Timestamp (Range), state to partition data. If my shard key is unique then won't it degrade performance? Also if my data is not huge & lets say there is a pattern for the shard key then won't it better to shard on the same machine for faster response times?

Comment: Sharding is a whole other bag of worms. I recommend going through Kristina's post on selecting a shard key to better understand:  http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/